# How to use trigger to insert data from 2 different tables

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I am new in coding currently learning about databases in SQL Server 2019

I have 3 tables `OrderInfo`, `EmployeeSales` and `SalesInfo`.

`OrderInfo` has the following columns:

```
OrderId, customerId, EmployeeId, ProductId, ShipAddress
```

In `SalesInfo`, I have these columns:

```
OdrId, ProdId, ProdName, ProdQuantity, ProdPrice, ShipAdd
```

In `EmployeeSales` with the following columns

```
OdrId, EmpId, ProductId, ProductName, ProductQuan, ProductPrice
```

I want to insert data automatically using a trigger.

`Empid` and `OdrId` should be inserted from `OrderInfo` and the remaining details of `EmployeeSales` should be inserted from `SalesInfo`. How can I achieve insert and update automatically?

I can delete automatically using on delete cascade

Comment: Why do you need EmployeeSales at all? It's data calculated from other two tables, you can just use a JOIN to get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join and trigger to insert to EmployeeSales

if EmployeeSales has relate with SalesInfo (a.OdrId, ProdId)

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trigger_OrderInfo
ON OrderInfo
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

insert into EmployeeSales
(OdrId, EmpId, ProductId, ProductName, ProductQuan, ProductPrice)
select  b.OrderId,b.EmployeeId,b.ProductId,a.ProdName,a.ProdQuantity,a.ProdPrice from SalesInfo a
inner join inserted b on a.OdrId=b.OrderId and a.ProdId=b.ProductId

end
```

Comment: What if the data is inserted into OrderInfo before SalesInfo :)

Comment: if  SalesInfo had data  that you can insert data into EmployeeSales

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really just want a `VIEW`, this avoids you having to maintain another table and keep it in sync.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.EmployeeSales
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  o.OrderId,
  o.EmpId,
  s.ProductId,
  s.ProductName,
  s.ProductQuan,
  s.ProductPrice
FROM dbo.OrderInfo o
JOIN dbo.SalesInfo s
  ON s.OrderId = o.OrderId
 AND s.ProductId = o.ProductId;
```

If you have performance problems when querying this view, you should ensure your tables are correctly indexed on the join columns. If that does not help then you can actually index the view itself.

---

I note that your table design is somewhat strange. `OrderInfo` and `SalesInfo` seem to both represent the relation `Order_Product`, but `OrderInfo` contains information that also relates to the whole order. So I would have expected `ProductId` to be removed from `OrderInfo` so that you only have one row per order, not per product.